# Selector to get direct parent of element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to write custom JS for a sharepoint webpart. Therefore I need to find each TableRow which has a child containing a hyperlink to a PDF file.

Till now I used following selector:

```
$('tr:has("a[href$="pdf"]")')
```

The main problem is that the parent of said hyperlink is nested in multiple tablerows.

I can't change this layout.

It's basically:

```
<tr>
  <tr>
    <tr>
      <a href=".pdf" />
    </tr>
  </tr>
</tr>
```

I only do want to find the direct parent of my hyperlink. How do I do this? 
I don't want to use :

```
 $('a[href$="pdf"]').parent()
```

Comment: What do you mean by direct parent?Immediate parent?

Comment: Any reason `$('a[href$="pdf"]').closest('tr')` wouldn't work?

Comment: That'll do the trick. Is there no way to include it into the selector?

Comment: Note that TR should not have A as child. Browsers will rearrange the DOM in such cases. Are you sure there is no TD in between?

Comment: There is a TD above it. I just want to shorten the scenario. That's why I used  $('a[href$="pdf"]').parent().parent() before the mention of .closest() :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that the level of nesting will always be 3, use this:

```
$('tr tr tr:has(a[href$=pdf])')
```

Otherwise, this will work:

```
$('tr:has(a[href$=pdf]):not(:has(tr))')
```

Here it is in a snippet (I've used `<div>`s instead of `<tr>`s for brevity's sake):

```js
var selected = $("div:has(a[href$=pdf]):not(:has(div))");
selected.addClass('selected');
```

```css
div {
    border: 2px solid gray;
    padding: 6px;
}

.selected {
    border-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <a href="http://example.com/foo.pdf">foo.pdf</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

...but frankly `$('a[href$=pdf]').closest('tr')` is probably more performant.